# How to test if a proxy server is working or not?

Tags: c#, proxy

I've got a pretty big list with proxy servers and their corresponding ports. How can I check, if they are working or not?

Comment: I don't quite see how this pertains to C#.  Furthermore I think this type of question would be better served over at serverfault.com

Comment: On second thought, I guess he's asking how to check if they are _working_ using C# code.

Comment: You can ping them as specified below or you get send an HttpWebRequest to a website and check if it works.

Comment: Perhaps see this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249702/what-is-the-fastest-way-for-checking-a-big-proxy-list-on-a-specific-web-site/23558724#23558724

Answer (score 12):

Working? Well, you have to use them to see if they are working.

If you want to see if they are online, I guess `ping` is a first step.

There is a [Ping class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping) in .NET.

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

private static bool CanPing(string address)
{
    Ping ping = new Ping();

    try
    {
        PingReply reply = ping.Send(address, 2000);
        if (reply == null) return false;

        return (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success);
    }
    catch (PingException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ping does NOT make sure  whether you can surf google or other websites .  i try to browse a site. it redirects to router page or some absurd page. you gotta   download html and check if contains specific word for site you are checking.  ie: google.com contains  the word "schema.org". if htmlsourceCode contains then you can browse surf internet with that proxy.

Comment: I agree with @bh_earth0, pinging it isn't enough. How do you check if the credentials provided to the proxy are the right ones? (If not you get access denied and oftentimes you don't know if its the proxy or the firewall blocking your request)

Answer (score 2):

I like to do a WhatIsMyIP check through a proxy as a test.

```
using RestSharp;

public static void TestProxies() {
  var lowp = new List<WebProxy> { new WebProxy("1.2.3.4", 8080), new WebProxy("5.6.7.8", 80) };

  Parallel.ForEach(lowp, wp => {
    var success = false;
    var errorMsg = "";
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    try {
      sw.Start();
      var response = new RestClient {
        //this site is no longer up
        BaseUrl = "https://webapi.theproxisright.com/",
        Proxy = wp
      }.Execute(new RestRequest {
        Resource = "api/ip",
        Method = Method.GET,
        Timeout = 10000,
        RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
      });
      if (response.ErrorException != null) {
        throw response.ErrorException;
      }
      success = (response.Content == wp.Address.Host);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      errorMsg = ex.Message;
    } finally {
      sw.Stop();
      Console.WriteLine("Success:" + success.ToString() + "|Connection Time:" + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "|ErrorMsg" + errorMsg);
    }
  });
}
```

However, I might suggest testing explicitly for different types (ie http, https, socks4, socks5).  The above only checks https. In building the ProxyChecker for https://theproxisright.com/#proxyChecker, I started w/ the code above, then eventually had to expand for other capabilities/types.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the used references and/or NUGET package names so I can run this example quicky in LinqPad.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static bool SoketConnect(string host, int port)
{
    var is_success = false;
    try
    {
        var connsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        connsock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendTimeout, 200);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        var hip = IPAddress.Parse(host);
        var ipep = new IPEndPoint(hip, port);
        connsock.Connect(ipep);
        if (connsock.Connected)
        {
            is_success = true;
        }
        connsock.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        is_success = false;
    }
    return is_success;
}
```

Comment: Good question, i thought you meant the timeout at first.

Comment: Is host the hostname of the proxy, and port its port? How do I check if authentication against the proxy worked?

Answer (score 0):

```
string strIP = "10.0.0.0";
int intPort = 12345;

  public static bool PingHost(string strIP , int intPort )
    {
        bool blProxy= false;
        try
        {
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(strIP ,intPort );

            blProxy = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error pinging host:'" + strIP + ":" + intPort .ToString() + "'");
            return false;
        }
        return blProxy;
    }

    public void Proxy()
    {
        bool tt = PingHost(strIP ,intPort );
        if(tt == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("tt True");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("tt False");
        }
```