# VB.Net Webrequest timeout doesn't work for invalid proxy

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have been using many proxies and few can be wrong/invalid proxy so timeout mostly doesn't work for it. I am not sure if dns can't resolve or what is issue exactly. I have used

```
    Dim req As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    req.Proxy = New WebProxy(proxy)
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    req.Timeout = 10000
    req.ReadWriteTimeout = 10000
    Dim res As HttpWebResponse = CType(req.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim stream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
    Dim streamreader = New StreamReader(stream)
    source = streamreader.ReadToEnd()
    streamreader.Close()
```

It works all well for valid proxies but if proxy is dead/invalid timeout doesn't work and it keeps waiting for like 5 - 10 min which i don't want. Any kind of help will be great :)

Comment: Your code is VB and you tag it as c#, You can set the timeout and check the proxy, if it's timeout mark it invalid. for  checking proxy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875130/c-sharp-how-to-test-if-proxy-is-working-or-not?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: if i use tcpclient with wrong/invalid proxy then will it work or have same issue?

Comment: It sometime take minutes to timeout, I was having this result last time. If you found the proxy taking more time you can mark it as invalid by yourself. see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1062628/713789 you can implement it with Timer class in C#

Comment: I am using multiple threads so won't be good choice to mark them timeout for each thread. I have used IAsyncResult interface but it's not reliable way.

Comment: "won't be good choice to mark them timeout for each thread" How you want to sort out this, I means simply tell user that your proxy is invalid or something else ?

Comment: Try setting ReceiveTimeout https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx